# Conditions in the On Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I am using SQL Server 2008.

Whats is the difference between :

With conditions in the `Where` clause

```
select customer.Id,
       order.Id
  from Customer customer
      left outer join Order order on order.customerId = customer.Id
  where 
      order.deleted =0
```

With conditions on the `ON` clause

```
select customer.Id,
       order.Id
  from Customer customer
      left outer join Order order 
           on order.customerId = customer.Id 
           and order.deleted =0
```

And how do the two compare with

```
select customer.Id,
       order.Id
  from Customer customer
      inner join Order order on order.customerId = customer.Id
  where 
      order.deleted =0
```

Comment: No difference with where you specify the `WHERE` (as long as it applies to that joined table). Then you're using an `INNER JOIN` which will return the matches of both tables. A `LEFT OUTER JOIN` will return the left table, and matched or non-matched (`NULL`) results of the right table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should learn about `sql joins`. Here is a [nice link](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/13/sql-server-introduction-to-joins-basic-of-joins/) to start.

Basically,

- **Case 1**: You are filtering `order.deleted =0` which could be `null` as it
  is the `right table of a left join`.If right table does not have a mapping row, columns from that table will be null. It should be as `ISNULL(order.deleted,0)=0` Or `order.delete IS NULL or order.delete=0`
- **Case 2**: `ON` is the condition where the two tables are joining and
  condition `order.deleted =0` is checked (I think) before the join
- **Case 3**: Simple `JOIN or INNER JOIN` where exact rows are mapped from both sides

Comment: [How I feel about w3schools](http://www.w3fools.com) ... [Better resource to learn about `JOIN`s](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/13/sql-server-introduction-to-joins-basic-of-joins/)

Comment: @nik. Thanks for the thing about w3school. I also like Pinal Dave's examples and explanations. Changed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Put them all in a query window in SSMS and type `ctrl+l` (or turn the option on that shows the actual execution plan after the query runs) and see the plans SQL generates.  It will tell you how it's different.  SQL will make decisions about queries to make it optimally perform, which can vary depending on your system (i.e. indexes, etc).

Doing a LEFT JOIN may end up with a different execution plan unless SQL can say "hey, you're saying LEFT JOIN but your WHERE clause basically makes it function like an INNER JOIN" and fixes/optimizes things for you.

Answer (score 0):

let us you have two tables

**Customer**

```
ID  
1   
2   
3
```

**Order**

```
ID  Customer
------------    
1   1
2   2
3   2
```

The customer 3 does not have any order.

And when a left join is done from `CUSTOMER` to `ORDER` the columns in the `ORDER` table will be null for customer 3. So if the condition is on where statement, customers with no order will not be returned. If the condition  is in 'on' those orders will not be included.

Answer (score 0):

Let me specifically answer your question.

The first and third queries are identical in results, if not in execution plans.  The `where` clause is looking at a field in the second table of a `left outer join`.  Any row in the first table but not the second will have NULL values and be filtered out.

The second query will keep all rows in the first table along with all their orders (if any).